# Using selenium to webscrape but getting different text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am making a webscraper with Python using Selenium. The goal is to load the website, search a value, and then get the online rate.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Opening the website and grabbing the data
driver.get('https://www.sunbeltrentals.com/equipment/detail/1255/0350140/7500lb-mini-excavator/')

# Finding the search box, entering a state, and then loading it
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[14]/section[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/ul/li/span/input')
search.send_keys("North Carolina")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[14]/section[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]').text

print(price)
```

and the output is this:

```
Enter the zip code of your job site for pricing.
Submit
```

I tried to make this webscraper using BeautifulSoup and it printed the data but there were placeholders where the actual numbers were because the website sends out a post request to 3 sites to get the location data and prints it. I couldn't figure how to do that and someone recommended Selenium so I tried this, but I can't get the actual text I am looking for. My ultimate goal is to eventually build a loop to search for different states.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your question is but I noticed something in your code that might be causing you issues, and I can give you some general advice based on my experiences with selenium.

The first is that your xpath is very specific! This can be a problem because the slightest change in the website will throw out an error - for example an advert might appear. Ideally you want to be as general as possible, using elements id, class, name or link text.

Try using any of the following:

```
 .find_element_by_css_selector(*selector*)
 .find_element_by_id(*id*)
 .find_element_by_link_text(*text*)
 .find_element_by_name(*name*)
 .find_element_by_class_name(*class*)
```

So if the field in which you want to send keys has a specific id, use that instead. For example you could write:

```
 browser.find_element_by_id('state')
```

It would be an amazing guess if this website did indeed have an id called 'state' so you are likely going to have to look for it.

The second thing I noticed is that you can just use the .submit() method on search instead of .send_keys(Keys.RETURN), i.e.

```
 search.submit()
```

Personally, I would look for a search 'button' and click it. I've always found that pressing enter or submitting the form is a little precarious. For example:

```
 find_element_by_id('search').click()
```

Or something like that. People may disagree with me and say its unnecessary, but I found it works better than just submitting.

The final piece of advice I have for you is to tell selenium to wait for something to appear. You can use conditional (link below), or you can use the simple time.sleep() function. I often find that selenium does things so quickly that the website/your internet connection can't keep up. Essentially selenium looks for an element that hasn't been loaded yet, then throws out an error.

Anyway, I really hope you are able to get something from this answer. Next time you post a question, try to phrase it in the form of a question rather than a confused statement.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To get the price value.Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and following `xpath`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.sunbeltrentals.com/equipment/detail/1255/0350140/7500lb-mini-excavator/')
search=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"address")))
search.send_keys("North Carolina")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='menu']"))).text)
```

**Output**:

```
1 Day: $445 USD 1 Week: $1,125 USD 4 Weeks: $2,440 USD
```